# Get all the word enter in text widget to an array

Tags: perl, perltk

I am new to Tk/Perl. Below is the simple GUI interface i create using tk/perl.

[GUI INTERFACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yrep.png)

Below is part of the code create this GUI.

```
$f2_label=$f_frame_top0->Label(-text=>"File",-font=>[-family=>'MS Sans Serif',-size=>9,-weight=>'bold',-underline=>0],-justify=>'left')->pack(-side=>'left',-anchor=>'w',-padx=>1,-pady=>1,);
$f2_entry=$f_frame_top0->Entry(-width=>50,-state=>"normal")->pack(-side=>'left',-anchor=>'w',-padx=>1,-pady=>1,-fill=>'x',-expand=>1);
$f2_file_btn=$f_frame_top0->Button(-text=>"...", -height=>1, -width=>2, -command=> [\&file_search,$tab2,$f2_entry,"TXT"])->pack(-side=>'left',-anchor=>'w',-padx=>1,-pady=>1);

$f3_label=$f_frame_top1->Label(-text=>"Number",-font=>[-family=>'MS Sans Serif',-size=>9,-weight=>'bold',-underline=>0],-justify=>'left')->pack(-side=>'left',-anchor=>'w',-padx=>1,-pady=>1,);
$f3_entry=$f_frame_top1->Text(-width=>10,-height=>10,-wrap=>'word',-state=>"normal")->pack(-side=>'left',-anchor=>'w',-padx=>1,-pady=>1,-fill=>'x',-expand=>1);


$but1_close=$f_frame_bot->Button(-text=>"Close",-command=>sub {destroy $mw}) ->pack(-side=>"right",-anchor=>'e',-padx=>1,-pady=>1);
$but1_exe=$f_frame_bot->Button(-text=>"Run",-command=>[\&fablot_fusesort,$f2_entry,$f3_entry] ) ->pack(-side=>"right",-anchor=>'e',-padx=>1,-pady=>1);

sub fablot_fusesort{
     my $file1 = shift -> get();
     my $number = shift ->get();
}
```

i want to get the number user enter in Text (the 22,23,24,25,26) to process in my subroutine but i not able to get it from shift -> get(). Any way i can get all the number user enter in the Text Widget? Thanks for helping

Comment: what about `my $numValue = $f3_entry->get();` so then you can move them to array....

Comment: @ssr1012 when i using get it show up this error message "wrong # args: should be ".notebook.sheet_3.frame1.text get index1 ?index2"

Comment: could you please update your question with minimal sample perl file for compile the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for the `get()` method on a `Tk::Text` object is described in the documentation for [`Tk::Text`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/pod/Text.pod):

> `$text->get(index1, ?index2?)`
>
> Return a range of characters from the text. The return value will be
>   all the characters in the text starting with the one whose index is
>   `index1` and ending just before the one whose index is `index2` (the
>   character at `index2` will not be returned). If `index2` is omitted then
>   the single character at `index1` is returned. If there are no characters
>   in the specified range (e.g. `index1` is past the end of the file or
>   `index2` is less than or equal to `index1`) then an empty string is
>   returned

So using `get()` without an argument is an error.

Here is an example of how to get the text:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new(); 

my $entry = $mw->Text(
    -width=>20, -height => 10, -wrap => 'word', -state => "normal"
)->pack(
    -padx => 1, -pady => 1, -fill => 'x', -expand => 1
);

my $button = $mw->Button(
    -text => "Run",
    -command=> sub { fablot_fusesort($entry) }
)->pack(
    -padx => 1, -pady => 1
);

sub fablot_fusesort{
    my ( $entry) = @_;
    my $text = $entry->get('1.0','end'); # <-- Gets all the text in the widget
    print "$text";
}
MainLoop;
```

Comment: Thanks , i able to get the word but i am not sure why when i print the $test i show out this error instead " Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at line 218.

Comment: Great. Can you show how you print? If `$test` is empty (`undef`) you will get that error...